# Dynamically change Yup message in Array custom validation. Return Array error messages

Tags: validation, yup

**Task:**
I need to check every element in the array - unique item.
And I want to show the user, where exactly he has failure string(like a, in the second and third fields you have an identical values).

**My solution**
So, I found a solution using `Yup.Array().test(...)`, and more concrete there it is:

```js
export const arrayValidation =
    Yup.array()
        .min(1)
        .max(5)
        .of(Yup.string().required("Required"))
        .test(
            'unique',
            (value) => {
                const message = "The value must be an unique, but you have the copy in the field "
                const uniqueFieldIds: (string | null)[] = [];

                for (let i = 0; i < value.originalValue.length; i++) {
                    const targetStr = value.originalValue[i];

                    for (let j = 0; j < value.originalValue.length; j++) {
                        const str = value.originalValue[j];

                        if(j !== i && targetStr === str) {
                            uniqueFieldIds.push(message + (j + 1));
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!uniqueFieldIds[i]) {
                        uniqueFieldIds[i] = null;
                    }
                }

                console.log("uniqueFieldIds: ", uniqueFieldIds);
                return uniqueFieldIds;
            },
            (value) => {
                return value ? value.length === new Set(value)?.size : true;
            }
        )

arrayValidation.validate(["test UNIQUE", "fail", "fail"])
    .then(result => console.log("success: ", result))
    .catch(error => console.log("error: ", error)) // => Why is it not the array?
```

**Problem**
But when `.test()` function returns an array - I have an error **string**(not array string).
If array has 2 identical lines, then error is "2 error occured", but `test()` return value is array, soft of

```
["The value must be an unique, but you have the copy in the field 2", "The value must be an unique, but you have the copy in the field 1"]
```

**EDIT:**
We can get the array just like that:

```js
arrayValidation.validate(["test UNIQUE", "fail", "fail"])
    .then(result => console.log("success: ", result))
    .catch(error => console.log("error: ", error.errors)) // => our array
```

BUT how to get the array in the formik? For some reason I get only string, and not array.

Here is an example:

```js
import {useFormik} from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import {useEffect} from "react";

export const arrayValidation =
    Yup.array()
        .min(1)
        .max(5)
        .of(Yup.string().required("Required"))
        .test(
            'unique',
            (value) => {
                const message = "The value must be an unique, but you have the copy in the field "
                const uniqueFieldIds: (string | null)[] = [];

                for (let i = 0; i < value.originalValue.length; i++) {
                    const targetStr = value.originalValue[i];

                    for (let j = 0; j < value.originalValue.length; j++) {
                        const str = value.originalValue[j];

                        if(j !== i && targetStr === str) {
                            uniqueFieldIds.push(message + (j + 1));
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!uniqueFieldIds[i]) {
                        uniqueFieldIds[i] = null;
                    }
                }

                console.log("uniqueFieldIds: ", uniqueFieldIds);
                return uniqueFieldIds;
            },
            (value) => {
                return value ? value.length === new Set(value)?.size : true;
            }
        )

arrayValidation.validate(["test UNIQUE", "fail", "fail"])
    .then(result => console.log("success: ", result))
    .catch(error => console.log("error: ", error.errors))

const TestComponent = () => {
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            arrayStrings: ["test UNIQUE", "fail", "fail"],
        },
        validationSchema: Yup.object({
            arrayStrings: arrayValidation,
        }),
        onSubmit: (values, {setSubmitting}) => {
            // ...
            setSubmitting(false);
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        formik.submitForm();
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("errors: ", formik.errors.arrayStrings); // "errors occurred" (string)
        console.log("TYPEOF errors: ", typeof formik.errors.arrayStrings); // string, (not object)
        console.log("errors: ", (formik.errors.arrayStrings as any).errors); // undefined
    }, [formik.errors])

    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TestComponent;
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your answers

Comment: you want to see error message as array `["The value must be an unique, but you have the copy in the field 2", "The value must be an unique, but you have the copy in the field 1"]` instead of `2 error occured` ? Use `.catch(error => console.log("error: ", error.errors ))`

Comment: It's work nice, thank you. But when I'm trying to integrate this logic to the Formik, I can't to get the the array anyway.

Comment: I add reproducible example for this one. It's really strange for me.

Comment: you can do one thing `return uniqueFieldIds.toString()` this will show whole array message but in string form

Comment: I see that in your example for Yup.test(), there are 2 functions inside...(value) => {}...I did not understand what is the 2nd function for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand there are no a normal way using React. Yes, you'll be able to do this in vanilla js:

```js
arrayValidation.validate(["test UNIQUE", "fail", "fail"])
    .then(result => console.log("success: ", result))
    .catch(error => console.log("error: ", error.errors)) // error.errors object
```

But in the React+Formik you can only:

1. concatenate resulting string using strArray.toString() or example using strArray.join().
2. Then you ought to parse this string in the formik.
3. And then use the value from the parsed string

Thanks to [@usama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13405106/usama) for the comments that helped to create this answer

Comment: is there any difference between using .validate() V/s calling triggerValidation() ?