# React Handle server side validation error message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, react-hook-form, yup

For my React app, I have a Yup validation schema defined as below;

```
export const mySchema = {
    ['my-add']: yup.object().shape({
        'myId': yup
            .string()
            .nullable()
            .required()
            .max(9, `Max length 9`)
            .test(
                'api-error',
                '${serviceErrorMsg}',
                async function(value, ctx) {
                    console.log(value);
                    console.log(ctx);
                    const {
                        isServiceError,
                        serviceErrorMsg
                    } = this.options.context;
                    if (isServiceError) {
                        return false;
                        //return ctx.createError({ path: 'myId', message: serviceErrorMsg }); //Not able to do this for some reason, 
                    }
                    return true;
                    
                }
            )
    })
}
```

I want to validate 'myId' field based on API response and accordingly display error message below the field if server gives me validation error for this field.

In my consuming component, I have

```
const {triggerValidation, setError} = useForm({});
//...
//...API call
    const context = { isServiceError: response.errorFlag, serviceErrorMsg: response.errorMessage};
    await mySchema['my-add'].validate(props.formRef.current.getValues(), {context}).catch((err) => {
        // logging err here gives below
        setError(err.params.path, 'api-error', response.errorMessage); 
    });
```

Logging "err" in the catch block gives below

```
ValidationError: undefined
    at createError (createValidation.js?f6e7:42:1)
    at eval (createValidation.js?f6e7:60:71)
```

Now, with the setError under the catch, I can see the error message displayed below the field.
However, I am not sure if this is the correct way to handle/display the validation error message.

I was instead wanting/trying to display the error message via
ctx.createError() in my Yup definition, as I have shown in the commented code. But, that does not work for some reason.

Please comment if handling the validation error in the catch block, the way I have done here is correct.

P.S: I am using a wrapper library based on React Hook Forms similar to Formik in my app.

I can somehow see similar pattern being followed in the example shown here;

https://dev.to/buschco/validate-like-a-pro-everywhere-with-yup-2phn

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75632176/dynamically-change-yup-message-in-array-custom-validation-return-array-error-me#comment133489750_75632176